# take only text from a certain line of multi-line Python String

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written a script in Python that pulls in the body of a multi-line email. I want to grab all the text on a line containing a hashtag, except for the hashtag itself and dump it into a list. The code is below and I've isolated a small portion that is relevant:

Email Body:

```
#Delete 454454

 

John Smith

+1.555.555.5555
```

Desired Output:

```
[454454]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Just loop through the file, check if a line starts with a `#`, and append `line[1:]` to a list.

Comment: Can the hashtag change (can we have `#apply 434984`)? Do you define hashtag by anything following a hash (`#`)? Is there a space after the hashtag?

Comment: Your edit makes the desired output make no sense any more...  I think you need to make another edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use regex:

```
>>> my_string
'#Delete 544574\n#Delete 457545\n \n\nThis email body contains two examples here.'
>>> import re
>>> map(int,re.findall("#.* (\d+)\n",my_string))
[544574, 457545]
```

its working on your edit:

```
>>> my_new
'#Delete 454454\n\n \n\nJohn Smith\n\n+1.555.555.5555'
>>> map(int,re.findall("#.* (\d+)\n",my_new))
[454454]
```

Comment: works. great answer. better than mine would be. really +1

Comment: @palsch thanks, some one did downvote dont know why

Comment: This works great in my example where the multi-line string is made with `\n`, but does not work when I integrate into my code. It returns a blank list. Any idea?

Comment: @user2242044 if you give real input to us, we can code better

Comment: maybe you should open a new question...

Comment: I added a copy paste from the original email body but change the name and phone number so I'm not giving out personal information.

Comment: @user2242044 check its working

Comment: @Hackaholic so it seems to work when I build the string with \n, but when the input comes from email it does not. I could provide the code I use, but the email and Inbox folder wouldn't exist for you

Comment: @user2242044 remove `\n` from re.findall and try

Comment: that did the trick. I should have seen that!

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this,

```
>>> s = '''#Delete 544574
... #Delete 457545'''
>>> [int(item.split()[1]) for item in s.splitlines() if item.startswith('#')] 
[544574, 457545]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build the list using comprehension, like that (assuming your lines are in the object `lines`, an iterable):

```
[int(line[8:-1]) for line in lines if line.startswith('#Delete ') and line[8:-1].isdigit()]
```